Compiling .NET 8 Class Library which uses Grpc NuGets to one .dll
Cant find the best way to compile my class library to convinient files for installing in other projects. Library uses gRPC, which probably is the issue, but even when i try to add reference to all created dll's, I still have error. Tried to pack into NuGet and install locally, but I have problem with installing this in other projects, it once works, once not.
I used:
dotnet nuget add source -n "MyLibs" C:\temp\

dotnet add .csproj_file package MyLib

dotnet nuget remove source MyLibs

Is there better way? I want to avoid many files.

You should probably focus on why the NuGet package sometimes fails to install. What error messages do you get when it fails?

It throws errors that it still cant find packages, sometimes Protobuf, sometimes Grpc,  and sometimes main class from my library library, I can't see the reason there. i have one console app, and two service worker apps, all in .NET 8, and console app works, one service workers once works, other time it doesn't xd Also, dotnet add doesnt change .csproj, but i can see my package in Visual Studio in NuGet tools
